# How can I check if my application has focus?

Tags: delphi, winapi, vcl, notification-area

What I want to do is check if my application has focus because if it is not then I will popup an Alert Window just over the Notification Area to display some message to the end user.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Call `Windows.GetForegroundWindow()` and then pass the `HWND` to the `Controls.FindControl()` function. It will return a non-nil `TWinControl` pointer if the `HWND` belongs to your process. For example:

```
if FindControl(GetForegroundWindow()) <> nil then
  // has focus ...
else
  // does not have focus ...
```

Answer (score 5):

D2007 has this useful property

```
if Application.Active then
//
```

Answer (score 4):

If your application consists of a single form, then

```
GetForegroundWindow = Handle
```

will suffice. The expression above is true if and only if the your form is the foreground window, that is, if keyboard focus belongs to a control on this form (or to the form itself).

If your application consists of a number of forms, simply loop through them and check if any of them matches `GetForegroundWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

A slight variation on Remys response is:

```
Var
  Win: TWinControl;
Begin
  Win := FindControl(GetForegroundWindow);
  if Win <> nil then
//      StringGrid1.Row :=5;
//      StringGrid1.SetFocus;
```

compiled ok for me, but I found it unreliable during debug, the stringgrid.setfocus is called even when the window isn't focused causing an error.